# Lines ending with ^M in my config files on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, bin

In my bash script, I am trying to change a configuration line one of my configuration file.
here is the bash script I used.

```
#!/bin/bash

jdbcURL(){
ssh ppuser@10.101.5.84 "sed -i \"s|\(\"jdbc.url\" *= *\).*|\1$2|\" $1"
}

jdbcURL $4 $5
```

After running this script, the configuration file is changed but the problem is, every lines in the configuration file is ending with ^M , so anything wrong in my bash script? Hope anyone help me. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^M` character is a carriage return - an extra character that Windows appends to newlines.  It is usually rendered as `\r`. `^M` is another visual representation.

You can strip them with the `dos2unix` utility:

```
$ dos2unix myfile
```

For reference, *nix operating systems (including OSX) use `\n` to delimit lines; Windows uses `\r\n`. Mac operating systems, up to [OS-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-9) used `\r` alone.

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering an issue with different line termination between Unixoid and Windoid worlds. Where Unix and consorts use a single 0x0a (linefeed) character, microsoft's world prefers 0x0d 0x0a  (carriage return, linefeed).  So if there is a file with lines ending with both carriage return AND linefeed looked at with unixoids, it interprets the linefeed as line terminator, and leaves the carriage return as part of the line, This is what you see as ^M

Conversion utilities to convert line terminators between these different conventions exist, but you ought to be able to let your sed expression take care of it.

As side note, Apple used to use another representation of line end, namely a single carriage return. I don't know whether they still do.

Comment: @Busmills Apple now uses a Unix OS and so uses lf